# Backbone.js fetch callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js and using fetch with options, but it doesn't seem to get the error or success callbacks, however data is being returned.

```
this.user.fetch({data: {username : this.username.val(), check : 'true'}}, {
    error: function(model, response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    success: function(model, response)  {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

This is what I have setup, am I missing something? It never hits error or success, but it does do the ajax request and it's returning data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing 2 separate arguments to `fetch`. Combine them into a single object with `data`, `success`, and `error` fields and it should work for you.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!  It's not returning the actual response though, it's going in the error function and it's returning some validation responses from within the model.

Comment: it seems like that would be a separate issue. glad you got this one taken care of!

Answer (score 0):

Example for x1a4 answer

```js
var myModel = new MyModel({id: modelId});
myModel.fetch({
  success: function (model) {
    console.log('success: model fetched');
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('error: loading model');
  }
});
```